# Using cygwin with python virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenvwrapper

I'm new to cygwin, not new to Python.

Trying to install cygwin on a system that already has Python and virtualenvwrapper installed and working fine. In CMD, I can type `workon myenv` and it works normally, however when I try to run the same command in cygwin bash I get a `command not found` error.

How do I get cygwin to recognize the command?

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

you can install python through the Cygwin installation tool

or

you have to execute your script with a full path to your python interpreter, this works in my case:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Launcher/python my_python_scritp.py
```

Comment: Thanks. Will having an cygwin-specific python installation conflict at all with my existing one? Perhaps I should just uninstall the existing python installation?

Comment: It won't be in conflict with your existing Python installation. I am using both, Cygwin and also windows installation without any problem. If you execute it from Cygwin it will use the Cygwin python, if from Windows it takes your Windows Python.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for your help!